# incompatible version of apache.camel with Spring.Boot v2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

Anyone could englighten me which org.apache.**camel** version I should use with the Spring boot version 2.0.0 .RELEASE.

When I used newer versions of apache.camel such like 2.21.0 , I come across with RelaxedPropertyResolved error. I read the forums and I was told to downgrade the version of Spring Boot which I cant. I have to use sprint.boot.version 2.0.0 with  a new apache.camel.version without making changes at my java code ?

Do you think is it possible?

These are my dependecies for camel.version and spring.boot.version. Please let me know if you need anything more.

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <version>2.21.0
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Error :

```
at com.project.eventrouter.Application.main(Application.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on 
org.apache.camel.spring.boot.security.CamelSSLAutoConfiguration due to 
org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not found. Make sure 
your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if 
you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a 
@ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:109)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:217)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:606)
... 13 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4):

- Camel 2.21.x or older is Spring Boot 1.5.x
- Camel 2.22.x is Spring Boot 2.0.x only
- Camel 2.23.x is Spring Boot 2.1.x (and potentially also Spring Boot 2.0.x)

Comment: i have another error after changing camel.version and spring.boot version.  Caused :  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd]

Comment: @Tonyukuk looks like you are using java 9, camel 2.x is java 8

Comment: No  luca i am using java 11.I cant use camel 2.x with java 11?

Comment: No Java 11 is not (yet) officially supported on Camel 2.x. Camel 3 is planned to support Java 11. We may be able to have best-effort support for Java 11 on a future Camel 2.x release but not at this time.

Comment: i don't know who made this happen to increase a minor version of a library(camel) when behind it the spring major version was increased but this was a very sad and contraproductive move, shouldn't let this happen